# Can we use Priority queue within synchronized block to make it thread safe, instead of using PriorityBlockingQueue

Tags: android, priority-queue

In my android application I am using PriorityQueue within synchronized block, so is it thread safe? I am not able to find out answer to my question.
Android doc itself says 'A PriorityQueue is not synchronized. If multiple threads will have to access it concurrently, use the PriorityBlockingQueue'.
Whatever we write within synchronizes block is threadsafe/synchronized. 
So the approach I am using, is it correct or needs to implement PriorityBlockingQueue?
Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your access to the PriorityQue are synchronised on the same object yes, it will be thread safe. Is there any reason why you don't want to use the already provided PriorityBlockingQue that is already synchronised by the API and will be less error prone when being used?

Comment: I just wanted to know the difference between PriorityQue with synchronized block and PriorityBlockingQue.

Comment: Performance wise they will probably be similar but you must make sure you always synchronise accesses while for PriorityBlockingQue that's already done. With your proposal there is additional work to be done for no real benefit.

Comment: You should also mark the response as accepted in this case to let other people know it's been answered and they shouldn't try to answer again.

Comment: I referred code for PriorityBlockingQue and most of them have used put() and take() within new thread, is it really needed? If PriorityBlockingQue itself handling everything then why to use new thread just to add and fetch entries from PriorityBlockingQue? can you provide me some good code to implement PriorityBlockingQue?

Comment: In my opinion the data structure classes that come as part of the platform have been properly tested and cover all corner cases. Unless they don't offer a certain functionality that you need I would just use them.